# Rails - no expected foreign keys after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

my app has 3 models, defined as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :insurance, through: :vehicle
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :insurance, dependent: :destroy
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

The resulting migration does not set any foreign keys for my insurances table. I expected to have two foreign keys, something like `user_id` and `vehicle_id`.

The resulting schema.rb file looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160314141604) do

  create_table "insurances", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "issue_date"
    t.date     "expiry_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "name"
    t.date     "matriculation_date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end

  add_index "vehicles", ["user_id"], name: "index_vehicles_on_user_id"

end
```

Why insurances table has no foreign keys? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following migrations:

`rails g migration AddUserIDToInsurances user:references`

`rails g migration AddVehicleIDToInsurances vehicle:references`

Then run `rake db:migrate`. This should add the two foreign keys you mentioned to your insurances table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically set the association keys in a migration. If you create a new migration and add:

```
add_column :vehicles, :user_id, :integer
add_column :insurances, :user_id, :integer

add_index :vehicles, :user_id
add_index :insurances, :user_id
# or whatever columns and indexes you need...
```

Rails gives you the `has_one` `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods to associate models conveniently with ActiveRecord, but the keys are not auto-generated unless you deliberately configure them in a migration file.

Comment: alright, I see. But why did Rails generate such keys the first time I run the migration only with User and Vehicle models? I mean that I automatically got the foreign key user_id in vehicles table after setting the relationships up in the models and running the migration.

Comment: What command did you use to create that migration? You would have had to specify the key either in the migration or with one of the generator flags upon creation. Rails doesn't just insert the key columns by default.

Comment: Yeah you are right, that was my mistake. I rolled back the migration, then edited the migration file adding t.belongs_to :vehicles, index: true and t.belongs_to :users, index: true and run rake db:migrate again to setup index and foreign keys